# is there a way to rewrite and simplify `decEq x x`?

Tags: idris

In the following code (which is an attempt to solve an exercise from 'Software Foundations' [chapter on Lists]), Idris reports a very complex type for `countSingleton_rhs`. The type includes a complex expression having the following at its core: `case decEq x x of ...`.

```
module CountSingleton

data NatList : Type where
  Nil : NatList
  (::) : Nat -> NatList -> NatList

-- count occurrences of a value in a list
count : (v : Nat) -> (s : NatList) -> Nat
count _ [] = Z
count Z (Z :: ns) = S (count Z ns)
count Z (_ :: ns) = count Z ns
count j@(S _) (Z :: ns) = count j ns
count (S j) ((S k) :: ns) =
  case decEq j k of
    Yes Refl => S (count (S j) ns)
    No _ => count (S j) ns

-- to prove
countSingleton : (v : Nat) -> (count v [v]) = S Z
countSingleton Z = Refl
countSingleton (S k) = ?countSingleton_rhs
```

Why isn't Idris simplifying `decEq x x` to `Yes Refl`?
Is there a better way to implement `count` which avoids this behaviour?
What can I do to simplify/rewrite the types in order to make progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count function is more splitted than it needs to. If you check for `decEq x y` anyway, you can unify all cases except `count _ [] = Z`:

```
count : (v : Nat) -> (s : NatList) -> Nat
count _ [] = Z
count x (y :: ns) = case decEq x y of
    Yes Refl => S (count x ns)
    No _ => count x ns
```

The straight-forward way to prove `countSingleton` is to follow the flow. Your `countSingleton_rhs` has a complex type, because the type is a case switch, depending on the result of `decEq v v`. Using `with` Idris can apply the result of the branch to the resulting type.

```
countSingleton : (v : Nat) -> (count v [v]) = S Z
countSingleton v with (decEq v v)
    | Yes prf = Refl
    | No contra = absurd $ contra Refl
```

---

As you have noted, this seems a bit redundant, as `decEq x x` is clearly `Yes Refl`. Luckily it is already proven in the library: `decEqSelfIsYes : DecEq a => decEq x x = Yes Refl`, which we can use to rewrite the resulting type:

```
countSingleton : (v : Nat) -> (count v [v]) = S Z
countSingleton v = rewrite decEqSelfIsYes {x=v} in Refl
```

Unfortunately because of [an open issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4001), rewriting `case` types doesn't always work. But you can just rewrite `count` with `with` to circumvent this issue:

```
count : (v : Nat) -> (s : NatList) -> Nat
count _ [] = Z
count x (y :: ns) with (decEq x y)
    | Yes _ = S (count x ns)
    | No _ = count x ns
```

Comment: I confirm that the above implementation of `countSingleton` using `with` works. Rewriting with `decEqSelfIsYes {x=v}` also works as long as `count` is also implemented using `with`. 

Rewriting with `decEqSelfIsYes {x=v}` does not work if `count` doesn't use `with`; it gives the following error:

```idris
When checking right hand side of countSingleton with expected type
        count v [v] = 1

Can't find implementation for DecEq a
```
providing {a=Nat} doesn't help either.

Perhaps I should file a bug for this?

thanks so much!